# Science project: second variable

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, watts, variable

I'm a completely new to electronic circuits and such and am currently learning to pull of this project where I'll be testing how temperature affects a battery's life.

Testing using a camera on time lapse recording 4 different AA battery powered light bulbs and seeing how long each will last. First dependant variable is of course the the time it takes for each bulb to stop,  it I'm not sure for the second.
Professor has suggested to me to try and find out the power(in watts) of each bulb, but not so sure about that one since I'm not too knowledgable. Anyone have any ideas of a other dependant variable that I can test? Assume that I have a voltmeter or ammeter 
Btw this is year 10 project

Comment: What do you mean "year 10 project"?

Comment: Similar to a science fair project, just gotta do an experiment, record it, make a report and stuff, but I'm just stuck on what to identify as a second dependant variable other than the time it takes for the bulbs to stop

Comment: Use flashlight bulb, use halogen bulb, use 28volt bulb, use 117VAC bulb. Some of these will NOT GET HOT, and their current drain will be 10X the expected current. I thus suggest you find ways (soldering iron) to heat these bulbs, and measure their current drain.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the data sheets of the batteries you intend to test. These should inform you how lifespan relates to discharge rates and, from this, you can design a load (most probably a constant current load) and then just monitor the falling battery voltage with time.

Because the current taken is constant and the voltage is monitored, the power consumed is simply V x I. Monitoring the lightbulb idea is plain daft because your camera will adjust its light sensitivity as the bulb dims. It's also daft because as the bulb dims it's resistance falls and therefore you have yet another variable to factor in. Simplicity is best.

Comment: A bit daft but not that daft. If it adjusts light sensitivity background will lighten as well. Student will perceive the difference.